# Mapping a function on chained pairs of elements from a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to map a function on chained pairs of elements from a list. Consider the list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

By using e.g. the function `f a1 a2 = a1 < a2`, I want to get:

```
[True,True,True,True]
```

The following seems to work in general:

```
zipWith f a (tail a)
```

However, I find it kind of hackish. Is there a more appropriate way, maybe using fold?

Comment: Well, how would you do it with a fold then?

Comment: What's hackish about using `zipWith f a (tail a)`? I'd say it's idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: `map f $ zip xs (tail xs)` would literally do what your title says. Or `[f x y | (x,y) <- zip xs $ tail xs]`. Whatever is more readable to you, they're all equivalent to the `zipWith` variant, which *is* shorter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I can speak on behalf of the Haskell community if I tell you that that is **the most idiomatic way** of doing this in Haskell. You could hack something together using a fold but it is clearly not as readable as the first variant:

```
f p xs = snd $ foldl (\acc x -> (x, snd acc ++ [p (fst acc) x])) (head xs, []) (tail xs)
```

---

Thank you @WillNess for supplying a more readable version of above's function, although it still does not beat `zipWith` in brevity and clarity.

```
f p = foldr g [] . tails where g (x:y:_) r = p x y:r; g _ _ = []
```

---

This is really hackish. The problem with using a fold in this situation is that normally the elements will be dealt with separately and they do not "know" about their neighbours. The only values they know are the accumulator and their own.

In this example, doing `f (<) [1,2,3,4,5]` will check if the left element of a pair is smaller than the one before, but it is **way** less readable than just doing:

```
f p xs = zipWith p xs (tail xs)
```

Usage would be the same as above.

---

Note that I am no professional in the Haskell language, so it may be that this approach using a fold could have been written in a better way, but nevertheless it will never beat the elegance of the `zipWith` approach.

Comment: I would've written `f p xs = snd $ foldr (\a (prev,res) -> (a, p a prev : res)) (last xs,[]) (init xs)` to keep the running time linear, but it's still not very elegant indeed (and it doesn't work for infinite lists :-)

Comment: @yatima2975 That is what I mean ^^

Comment: ``f p = foldr g [] . tails where g (x:y:_) r = p x y:r; g _ _ = []``. Which is a paramorphism in disguise. BTW ``zipWith p xs (tail xs) = (zipWith p <*> tail) xs``.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Traversable instance over a State functor to achieve the expected result, like so :

```
traverseSt :: Traversable t => (a -> a -> b) -> a -> t a -> t b
traverseSt f x ta = runState (traverse (\a -> get >>= \a' -> f a a'<$put a) ta) x
```

You may then specialize this function to work on non-empty lists (since you need to know at least one element to provide the first seed value), which looks like :

```
zipSelf :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
zipSelf f (a:as) = traverseSt f a as
zipSelf f [] = error "Impossible use of zipSelf on empty structure"
```

Splitting code in this way, you may also define `zipSelf` over other structures, such as `Tree`s or `Maybe`s, or any type for which a first element is easily extractible.

Cheerio,

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function like

```
movingApply :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
movingApply f (x:y:xs) = f x y : movingApply f (y:xs)
movingApply f _ = []
```

(feel free to pick a better name, this one is terrible), but this is computationally the same as `zipWith f x (drop 1 x)` when you expand it out.  Note that I've used `drop 1` instead of `tail`, this is because `tail` is a partial function, and `tail []` results in a runtime error while `drop 1 []` returns `[]`.  Since this is pretty much the same thing as the `zipWith` variety, I'd prefer `zipWith` since it's a one-liner and I don't have to do the recursion manually.

Comment: Actually, using `tail` is fine in `zipWith f xs (tail xs)`, even if the reason is a bit counterintuitive. The first case of the definition of `zipWith` is something like `zipWith f [] _ = []`, so we have that `zipWith f xs (tail xs)` will not evaluate `tail xs` when `xs==[]`.

Comment: @chi good point, but I like just using `drop 1` instead of tail everywhere because of partiality. Same with listToMaybe and head.

Answer (score 1):

You could use mapAccumL

```
import Data.List
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
compareAdjacent = snd $ mapAccumL (\acc x -> (x,(x > acc))) 0 a
```

This produces the output [True,True,True,True,True]. If you want it to ignore the first list item, you could create a function like this:

```
compareAdjacent' (x:xs) = snd $ mapAccumL (\acc x -> (x,(x > acc))) x xs
compareAdjacent' [] = []
```

Comment: just need to add `compareAdjacent' [] = []` case.