# Declaring functions

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm very new to haskell programing and have alot of difficulties quite sometime. The task I'm given here is that a have a list of numbers it then compares to another list of numbers and returns three numbers as feedback based on which interpretation on other numbers could be filtered.
eg.

[4,9],[7,9],[10,18],[2,9] is my list 
it should two separate lists now [4,9] and [7,9] it should give a feedback (1,1,0)

first function should check whether two lists have the same value if they have then it should return value 2, if there is only one value then it should return 1, no values then it returns 0
i tried to do this with `elem` method but im not able to succeed . So the answer for this must be 1 since it has 9 on both lists.

second function checks for the lowest value. It should only compare from the second element to the first. from the same example above [4,9] and [7,9] it first finds out the lowest value in [7,9] which is 7 and then checks for any value lower than 7 in [4,9], it there then it returns a feedback 1 else its 0

third function is the same as the second except it checks for the highest value 
eg . [[3,13],[10,9],[5,7]] we take first two elements of the list 
[3,13] and [10,9], now we check the highest number in [10,9] which is 10 and check for that value in [3,13] here the answer must be 1 since 13 is higher than 10 else it is 0

please help in declaring these functions 
would be much obliged

Comment: It really isn't very clear what you're wanting to accomplish.  From what you've said, it seems that you've at least attempted something.  Can you post that and possibly try to re-word your question to be more specific?  I know you've said that what you've tried doesn't work, but isn't that the point of stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing without seeing any sample code. I think I understand how your first function needs to  work:

It seems that you are using a list of lists, [[Int]] but all of your lists only have two items. It would be easier to use a pair [(Int,Int)]

Then your first function could be written with nested if statements:

`firstTest (a1,b2) (a2,b2) = if a1 == a2 && b1 == b2 then 2 else if a1 == a2 || b1 == b2 then 1 else 0`

If it can't be a pair and it must be a list of lists then it might be easier to reify your problem and turn the two lists into Sets using Data.Set. Comparing two sets is far more efficient than comparing two lists - and Data.Set provides us the useful `isSubsetOf` function. You can transform a list into a set using the `fromList` function.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
firstTest' :: S.Set Int -> S.Set Int -> Int
firstTest' sas sbs = if sas == sbs then 2 else if S.isSubsetOf sas sbs then 1 else 0
```

Comparing adjacent items in a list is a bit challenging. Take a look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25777940/3792504